# How can I join two tables with same fieldnames and return both in array using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
public function appProfile($id=null)
{
   $query= $this->db->where('software_db.id',$id)
                    ->from('software_db')
                    ->join('dev_db','software_db.dev_id=dev_db.id','right')
                    ->select(['dev_db.name','dev_db.id','software_db.id','software_db.name','software_db.file_name','software_db.image_name'])
                    ->get()
                    ->result_array();
    print_r($query);die;
}
```

The table structure is as follows:

```
dev_db(id(primary key),name,email,password,comany,skills)
software_db(id(primary key), name,file_name,image_name,description,platform,cateogory)
```

The output array never contains the id and name from dev_db. It should return all the fields from software_db where software.id=$id and name and id from dev_db.

Comment: Did you mean to join on `software_db.id=dev_db.id` rather than `software_db.dev_id=dev_db.id`

Comment: select shouldn't have [ ]

Comment: @drfranks3 no sir, it is 'software_db.dev_id=dev_db.id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select()` shouldn't have square brackets `[ ]`.

in your select clause create aliases, something like

```
->select('dev_db.name as dev_db_name') // etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Try is this way

```
public function appProfile($id = '') {

    $this->db->select('dev_db.name, dev_db.id, software_db.id, software_db.name, software_db.file_name, software_db.image_name');
    $this->db->from('software_db');
    $this->db->join('dev_db', 'dev_db.id = software_db.dev_id', 'right');
    $this->db->where('software_db.id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();

}
```

Comment: it is only returning the `name` field of dev_db